# Performance issue with reading integers from a binary file at specific locations in F#

Tags: .net, f#, binaryfiles, memory-mapped-files, binaryreader

This morning I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381090/performance-issue-with-reading-integers-from-a-binary-file-at-specific-locations) why my Python code was (a lot) slower then my F# version but I'm wondering whether the F# version can be made faster. Any ideas how I could create a faster version of the below code that reads a sorted list of unique indexes from a binary file with 32-bit integers? Note that I tried 2 approaches, one based on a BinaryReader, the other one based on MemoryMappedFile ([and some more on Github](https://github.com/samuelbosch/blogbits/blob/master/geosrc/AsciiToBin.fsx)).

```
module SimpleRead            
    let readValue (reader:BinaryReader) cellIndex = 
        // set stream to correct location
        reader.BaseStream.Position <- cellIndex*4L
        match reader.ReadInt32() with
        | Int32.MinValue -> None
        | v -> Some(v)

    let readValues fileName indices = 
        use reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        // Use list or array to force creation of values (otherwise reader gets disposed before the values are read)
        let values = List.map (readValue reader) (List.ofSeq indices)
        values

module MemoryMappedSimpleRead =

    open System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles

    let readValue (reader:MemoryMappedViewAccessor) offset cellIndex =
        let position = (cellIndex*4L) - offset
        match reader.ReadInt32(position) with
        | Int32.MinValue -> None
        | v -> Some(v)

    let readValues fileName indices =
        use mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileName, FileMode.Open)
        let offset = (Seq.min indices ) * 4L
        let last = (Seq.max indices) * 4L
        let length = 4L+last-offset
        use reader = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read)
        let values = (List.ofSeq indices) |> List.map (readValue reader offset)
        values
```

For comparison here is my latest numpy version

```py
import numpy as np

def convert(v):
    if v <> -2147483648:
        return v
    else:
        return None

def read_values(filename, indices):
    values_arr = np.memmap(filename, dtype='int32', mode='r')
    return map(convert, values_arr[indices])
```

**Update**
In contrary to what I said before here, my python is still a lot slower then the F# version but due to an error in my python tests it appeared otherwise.
Leaving this question here in case someone with in depth knowledge of the BinaryReader or MemoryMappedFile knows some improvements.

Comment: It's likely no one can answer this authoritatively without profiling your code, which you can do yourself.

Comment: With profiling you can only go so far. From my original python version I would never have found the numpy or hdf5 solution with profiling. As I'm not very experienced with reading binary files and memory mapped files in .NET I'm wondering if similar performance gains are possible.

Comment: What is the perf difference between the numpy and .NET memmap versions? Is the memmap version the fastest in F#?

Comment: The python version is still slower, found a bug in my testing code. The memmap version is slightly faster when reading e.g. 100 times 1000 values but a lot slower when reading 10000 times 10 values.

Comment: Aside from the two iterations fo your indices argument in your second implementation (Seq.min and Seq.max) all the relevant parts seem to be in the way the .net framework handles the IO.

Comment: If this is no longer an issue then the question should be closed.  SO is for specific problems, not for open-ended "can this be improved" type questions.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the SimpleReader 30% faster by using reader.BaseStream.Seek instead of reader.BaseStream.Position. I also replaced lists by arrays but this didn't change a lot.

The full code of my simple reader is now:

```
open System
open System.IO

let readValue (reader:BinaryReader) cellIndex = 
    // set stream to correct location
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(int64 (cellIndex*4), SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
    match reader.ReadInt32() with
    | Int32.MinValue -> None
    | v -> Some(v)

let readValues indices fileName = 
    use reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    // Use list or array to force creation of values (otherwise reader gets disposed before the values are read)
    let values = Array.map (readValue reader) indices
    values
```

The full code and versions in other languages are on [GitHub](https://github.com/samuelbosch/blogbits/tree/master/geosrc/binreaders).